# How to find username of a SSH server running on Debian

Tags: linux, windows, debian

I have installed openssh-server on my Debian build of Linux, and now I want to access the SSH server on my windows pc, with FileZilla, but I need to find the username and password of the server, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSH username and password is usually the same username and password you log in with on Debian. If you don't know your username, you can use the command `whoami`. The server address is just the ip of the server, and if all the devices are on the same network, you can use ifconfig to figure that out.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has let me access my SSH server, and add files into it!